# Chronicle how to increase processors?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

I am using Chronicle queue 5.16.8

I am getting this warning

```
net.openhft.chronicle.threads.Pauser     : Using Pauser.sleepy() as not enough processors, have 1, needs 8+
```

Is it possible to increase this processor ?

source code

My approach here is use a Chronicle Map for storing index reader. I guess, I can have the same behavior turn in on recordHistory ...

I had to use Jackson Json converted ... I didn't get how to use writeDocument method.

The While true loop, it another not nice thing that I have here ... I couldn't figure how to find last index in the queue.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMap;
import net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.ChronicleQueue;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.ExcerptAppender;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.ExcerptTailer;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.RollCycles;
import net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;



@Service
public class QueueService {

    public static final String INDEX = "index";

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // json converter

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    }

    public void write(List dtos, String path) throws Exception {

        try (ChronicleQueue queue = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.binary(path).rollCycle(RollCycles.DAILY).build()) {
            final ExcerptAppender appender = queue.acquireAppender();

            for (int i=0; i<dtos.size(); i++) {
                appender.writeText(mapper.writeValueAsString(dtos.get(i)));
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(Object dto, String path) throws Exception {

        try (ChronicleQueue queue = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.binary(path).rollCycle(RollCycles.DAILY).build()) {
            final ExcerptAppender appender = queue.acquireAppender();
            appender.writeText(mapper.writeValueAsString(dto));
        }
    }


    public List readList(String path, Class aClass) throws Exception {

        List dtoList = new LinkedList<>();

        try (ChronicleQueue queue = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.binary(path).build()) {

            final ExcerptTailer tailer = queue.createTailer();

            ChronicleMap<String, Long> indexMap = getReaderIndexMap(queue.fileAbsolutePath());

            if (indexMap.containsKey(INDEX)) {
                tailer.moveToIndex(indexMap.get(INDEX));
            }

            while (true) { // something smart ?

                String json = tailer.readText();
                if (json == null) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    dtoList.add(mapper.readValue(json, aClass));
                }
            }

            indexMap.put(INDEX, tailer.index());
            indexMap.close();
        }
        return dtoList;
    }

    public ChronicleMap<String, Long> getReaderIndexMap(String queueName) throws Exception {

        ChronicleMapBuilder<String, Long> indexReaderMap = ChronicleMapBuilder.of(String.class, Long.class)
                .name("index-reader-map")
                .averageKey(INDEX)
                .entries(1);

        ChronicleMap<String, Long> map = indexReaderMap.createPersistedTo(new File(queueName+"/reader.idx"));
        return map;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the number of available processors Java believes you have.

If you have a virtual machine, you can configure your host to have more CPUs.

If you have a physical machine, you can change your processor to one with more cores.

Or you can ignore the warning.

Busy pausing with only one CPU is probably not a good idea as it will use all the CPU you have.

NOTE: We generally recommend having at least 4 cores, even for development.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I miss understand the warning ... Now it's clear.

Comment: @JuanPabloG the problem.is when you have too many busy threads and not enough cpus. This can make the machine usable when instead it doesn't busy wait the code runs ok. Not fast but ok.

Comment: thanks again. I am running on a vmware esxi ... with one CPU assigned. I miss understand the warning ... I though was referring to numbers of threads and not CPU. 
For now it's working perfect. I don't to many messages for the moment either.

Comment: @JuanPabloG out of interest, are you using a Pauser?

Comment: @PeterSmith, not at all. I added my code maybe you wanna take a look, and for sure you will have some comments XD.

Comment: @JuanPabloG I was thinking about how to suppress this message if it's not really relevant to you.